# Thymeleaf: how to iterate over list, while using iteration variable in table row attribute

Tags: html, spring-thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf inside a Spring Boot application.

I have a Thymeleaf list variable "users_online", I can produce a table like so:

```
    <tbody id="users-online-list">
       <tr th:each="username: ${users_online}">
           <td th:text="${username}"></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

That works fine.  **However, what I want to do is add an id attribute in the *tr* element.**  For example, if the username is user1, this is what I would like for the row:

```
<tr id="online-user1">
  <td>user1</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried several variations of iterating like this one that doesn't work:

```
<tbody id="users-online-list">
   <tr th:each="username: ${users_online}"
       th:id="online-${username}">
       <td th:text="${username}"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have also tried to place the iteration inside the *tbody* element instead of the *tr* element, but that doesn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Thanks